# How can I create a child-extension class from Parent class named _Extension?

Tags: extension-methods, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm developping in **Visual Studio** for Dynamics 365.
I need to extend a class named with _Extension final name.
Below the details:

```
class MyParentClass_Extension
{
    str doSomething(int arg) 
   {
       // ...
   }
}
```

I would like to create a child class:

```
[ExtensionOf(classStr(MyParentClass_Extension))]
final class My ChildClass_Extension_Extension
{
    str doSomething(int arg) 
    {
        // Part 1
        var s = next doSomething(arg + 4);
        // Part 2
        return s;
    }
}
```

**I retrive a compile error.** 
There is any way to extend a class like mine?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, for the purposes of people who might be finding this q&a through google, would you be able to update the question with a copy&paste of the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to be running [Platform Update 26 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/fin-and-ops/get-started/whats-new-platform-update-26). It is only possible to extend extension classes once you are on PU26 or a later platform.

Under "Extensibility Enhancements" in the link I provided above, you will find a [link the third wave of extensibility enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/April19/dynamics365-finance-operations/platform-extensibility3). In here you will notice they have added the ability to extend extensions.

To answer your question: You are likely receiving the compile error because you are running a platform update prior to PU26.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand by your code, there are a total of 3 classes:

1. `MyParentClass`
2. `MyParentClass_Extension` which extends `MyParentClass`
3. `MyParentClass_Extension_Extension` which extends `MyParentClass_Extension`

Now when you create an extension you always set it as `final` which means that you can not extend this class further. In your case what I believe you already set `final` for `MyParentClass_Extension` class and the next child class `MyParentClass_Extension_extension` is trying to extend `MyParentClass_Extension` which is `final`. That's why you are getting an error.